# How do I create a simple title bar containing a logo, and preserve the logo's aspect ratio?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a simple page with a title bar at the top, and a logo in the left of the title bar. I'm new to flexbox and grid and not great at CSS, but it seems sensible and idiomatic to use grid for the main layout, give the title bar a sensible height, and then use flexbox for the title bar itself. But I keep getting results that aren't quite right.

Attempt #1 had a huge problem with image scaling. After reading [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#extrinsic) the scaling seemed like a cyclic dependency caused by one `</div>` too many. Also I hadn't yet heard of `object-fit` to control the image aspect ratio.

Attempt #2 is mostly fine. The only issue is the 'letterboxing' of the image: the image content is fine but its box is too wide, due to how margins are handled. Letterboxing is exactly what `object-fit: content` and `object-fit: scale-down` are defined to do, but it's not what I want.

Attempt #3 looks just how I want it. But I only achieved that by introducing variables and explicitly setting image width and height, which I was hoping to avoid by adopting grid + flexbox. It also relies on knowing the image's aspect ratio and to sizing accordingly.

Is there a simple way to include an image in my title bar, to preserve the image's ratio, and to avoid letterboxing?

Snippets below. Thanks!

**Attempt #1**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.titleBar {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}

.titleBar div {
  display: flex;
}

.titleBar img {
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="titleBar">
    <div>
      <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Attempt #2**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
}

.titleBar {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.titleBar img {
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 25px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="titleBar">
    <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Attempt #3**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  --border-size: 1px;
  --row-height: 150px;
  --img-margin: 10px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: var(--row-height);
}

.titleBar {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.titleBar img {
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  margin: var(--img-margin);
  max-height: calc(var(--row-height) - 2*var(--img-margin));
  max-width: calc(var(--row-height) - 2*var(--img-margin));
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="titleBar">
    <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Logos are usually made with specific widths/height, You first need to decided which element should define the height of the navbar, is it the image ir the content next to it

Comment: I'd like to be able to support a consistent height across pages/titlebars, with varying logos, and where the row height of some or all pages can be freely changed without forcing a 'resize all the images` exercise. This seems reasonable but if I'm wrong I'm wrong.

Comment: You can't leave content be what it want, at some point you will have to define a constraint, that constraint being a fixed or a flexible size will depend on what you're trying to do in the long run. The browser window gives a false feel that the width is set and therefore the height must be controlled alone. If the logo is changing then the navbar height should depend on the content

Comment: I reccomend you to look at here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: @ZohirSalak Thank you for the comments. The container explicitly sets a `grid-row-constraint`, which the img is able to use to set its height. And `object-fit: scale-down` (or `contains`) respects the aspect ratio, so there's no inherent need to explicitly set that either. I'm just looking for the right incantation for how to avoid letterboxing, since it seems possible. I'm also not sure why the navbar height should depend on the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is solved. There were 2 issues, one big and one little.

Issue #1 - the default `align-items` for flexbox is `stretch`. Since I'm taking up the whole height I didn't think that mattered, but deep in the [W3C CSS Box Alignment Spec (section 6.1)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#justify-self-property) it says this about `stretch`:

> Note: The stretch keyword can cause elements to shrink, to fit their container.

This was causing my logo container to shrink vertically which caused letterboxing. Changing to `align-items: center` fixed that.

Issue #2 was less of a problem and more straightforward. E.g. I was placing an image with a 5:1 aspect ratio, a 10px border and a max-height of 100% inside a grid row with a fixed height of 100px. The layout engine calced a box of 500x100. Perfect. However, once the 10px borders were laid out, that left a content area of 480x80, and that's not 5:1. So it had no choice but to stretch, clip, or letterbox the image, depending on `object-fit`.

I'm not sure if my solution to Issue #2 is the best, but I decided to go with `box-sizing: content-box`, and to calc my height as 100% - 2*border size. Everything works, for all images of all aspect ratios, and I never have to specify width.

Snippet with 3 examples with 3 different aspect ratios:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px dotted gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  ;
  padding: 0px;
  row-gap: 25px;
}

.titleBar2 {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  column-gap: 25px;
}

.titleBar2 img {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  --border: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: var(--border) solid lightgray;
  max-height: calc(100% - 2*var(--border));
  margin: 0px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="titleBar2">
    <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/1200/600' />
    <a href='https://www.fillmurray.com/1200/600' target='new'>https://www.fillmurray.com/1200/600</a>
  </div>
  <div class="titleBar2">
    <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/600/1200' />
    <a href='https://www.fillmurray.com/600/1200' target='new'>https://www.fillmurray.com/600/1200</a>
  </div>
  <div class="titleBar2">
    <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/2000/400' />
    <a href='https://www.fillmurray.com/2000/400' target='new'>https://www.fillmurray.com/2000/400</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```